# Google Docs gview viewer retired?

Tags: pdf, google-docs

I'm using the Google Docs viewer in multiple places on a few different websites.  This morning, none of them appear to be working and the raw URL returns a 400 error from Google.  Does anyone know if this service has been retired?  If so, are there other lightweight, entirely client side alternatives?
Here's an example that doesn't display for me:

```html
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.danburyschools.org/Downloads/2016FallSportsSchedulesD.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:718px; height:950px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

It was working a few days ago.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Interestingly enough, the first time I clicked "Run code snippet" on my the code above, it generated and displayed the first page.  Subsequent clicks did not display.  Is this an issue on Google's side?  How do I report it to them?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue and posted a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40414039/google-docs-viewer-returning-204-responses-no-longer-working-alternatives  There's a link on that page referencing a Google discussion where it appears they've phased it out.  So incredibly irritating!